# I'm getting an smtp error in vb.net project away from home

Tags: vb.net, smtp, sendmail

I have a sendmail function in a vb.net project that works perfectly.  Until I give it to others to try. I am sending an email to my work email address from my personal gmail email address. I'm using port 587 in code, which like I said, works fine at home In other words, it works at my house, but everywhere else I get the following error:

[image: error message]

any guidance, as always, will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code I am using:

```
    Try
            Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
            Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
            Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(My.Resources.email, My.Resources.pass)



            Smtp_Server.Port = 587
            Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
            Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

            e_mail = New MailMessage()
            e_mail.From = New MailAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com")
            e_mail.To.Add("xxxxxxx@jobxxxxx.org")
            e_mail.Subject = "A Student Has Just Been Counseled by " & cmbReferredBy.SelectedItem.ToString
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
            e_mail.Body = "A Notification was just created by " & sender & " Stating: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & txtDescriptionR.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Date.Now
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
            MsgBox("All Required Counseling Notifications Sent Successfully", vbSystemModal)

        Catch error_t As Exception
            MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
        End Try
```

Like I said earlier, the code works as expected when I'm home. It's when I take it somewhere else (on my laptop), or send the application to someone else to use that it throws that error.  That suggests to me the port, credentials, etc are fine.

Comment: Error messages are text. Post them as text, not as pictures, and format them appropriately. Also, don't add information in a comment that should have been in the question to begin with. Edit the question and add ALL the relevant information. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I moved the comment into the op as you suggested, but the error is an image because I don't have it as text. As far as I can tell it reads exactly the same as text since it is a picture of text.  In any event, did you have anything helpful, or just needed to flex some muscle and be critical?

Comment: If you don't want to be criticised then stop making it harder for people to answer your questions. This site is supposed to be used a certain way and you're not doing that. If you're not going to read how to use it for yourself then don't complain when someone tells you. I answer many questions here and I'd rather that I and others don't have to waste our time trying to get all the information we need in order to volunteer our time to help you. If you don't have the error message as text then get it. If, for instance, we want to search online for the error message, we can't copy a picture.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney Also, just to be clear on why I posted that image.  I can not reproduce the error at home because the code works.  The error was thrown when me and several others used it at work.  I wasn't running it out of visual studio, so I didn't have access to the text version of the error.  I hope that fills in some of the gaps I left.  I understand why text is better, but I didn't have access to it when it happened.

Comment: You can simply hit Crtl+C when a message box is displayed and the text will be copied to the Clipboard. It copies a bit more than just the message but a few seconds to delete the extraneous stuff and you have your stack trace as text.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says 'require secure connection' or 'client not authenticated' but you don't show your code for us to check.

Ensure you have .EnableSSL set True and the port number correct but I suspect it's authentication.  How are you passing your credentials?

Try setting 'UseDefaultCredentials' false and providing credentials as:

```
New NetworkCredential(SMTPUserName, SMTPPassword)
```

Where SMTPUserName name is your Gmail address and SMTPPassword is your email password.

However, as I said, without seeing your code, this is just a guess.

Comment: Thank you Jon.  The code already works, though.  I'm just trying to figure out why it doesn't work when others use it, or when I take it outside of my own house.  It seems like the attempts to send mail are being blocked, perhaps by other networks, but I'm not sure why, and that error doesn't reveal much.

Comment: Check how the network credentials are configured because if they are not explicitly set, they could differ on a different PC.  If you are sure the settings are correct, set up an email client on the remote PC using the same settings and try sending an email.  If that fails, trace that fault.  If that works, it must be in your code somewhere.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't responded guys.  I just spent 8 days in the hospital.  I will revisit this as soon as I am up to it.  Thanks again for all your input!

Comment: Ok...so here was the issue.  It was on an intranet, therefore credentials/SSL/etc were not necessary.  Once I removed the port, etc, etc it all worked.  Thanks again for all the responses!